# Hyper smooth and ultra smooth functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, fractional-calculus

So I was mixing smooth functions with fractional calculus when I came upon the following idea.  We could have functions in $D^\alpha$ defined as follows:

$f(x)\in D^1\iff\frac d{dx}f(x)=f'(x)$ exists.

$f(x)\in D^2\iff\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)=f''(x)$ exists.

$f(x)\in D^k\iff\frac{d^k}{dx^k}f(x)=f^{(k)}(x)$ exists.

$f(x)\in D^\omega\iff\forall k<\omega(f(x)\in D^k)$, which is equivalent to $f(x)$ being a smooth function.

Next, we need to define [fractional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus).  Per this question, I don't mind which fractional derivative you use, so long as it is one of the many well known and accepted fractional derivatives.

Now, we may extend our derivatives further to what I will call hyper smooth functions.

$f(x)\in D^{\omega+1}\iff\frac d{dt}f^{(t)}(x)=f^{(1,t)}(x)$ exists.

$f(x)\in D^{\omega+2}\iff\frac{d^2}{dt^2}f^{(t)}(x)=f^{(2,t)}(x)$ exists.

$f(x)\in D^{\omega+k}\iff\frac{d^k}{dt^k}f^{(t)}(x)=f^{(k,t)}(x)$ exists.

$f(x)\in D^{\omega2}\iff\forall\alpha<\omega2(f(x)\in D^\alpha)$

$f(x)\in D^{\omega2+k}\iff\frac{d^k}{du^k}f^{(u,t)}(x)=f^{(k,u,t)}(x)$ exists.

$f(x)\in D^{\omega3}\iff\forall\alpha<\omega3(f(x)\in D^\alpha)$

And so on, defining ourselves $D^\alpha$ for every $\alpha\le\omega^2$.  A function is called ultra smooth if we have:

$f(x)\in D^{\omega^2}\iff\forall\alpha<\omega^2(f(x)\in D^\alpha)$

---

> But are these functions unique?  Is $\{f(x)\in D^\omega\land f(x)\notin D^{\omega+1}\}$ an empty set or not?  It seems rather hard to find examples (and don't forget you are free to use whichever fractional derivative you choose).  In general, can a function be in $D^\alpha$ but not in $D^\beta$ for $\omega\le\alpha<\beta\le\omega^2$?

---

Assuming we enforce a domain restriction that everything must be $\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb R$, exponential functions are an appropriate example.  Under certain definitions and $a>0$, we have

$$\frac{d^t}{dx^t}a^x=a^x(\ln(a))^t$$

However, when $0<a<1$, we find that $\frac d{dt}\frac{d^t}{dx^t}a^x$ does not exist (as a function $\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb R$) and so this is an example of a function that is smooth but not hyper smooth.  Likewise this pattern can be used to show the existence of functions $f(x)\in D^{\omega k}$ and $f(x)\notin D^{\omega k+1}$.

However, I cannot find any examples where $f(x)\in D^{\alpha+1}$ but $f(x)\notin D^{\alpha+2}$.

Allowing functions to be $\mathbb C\mapsto\mathbb C$, I cannot find any other examples of this.

Comment: Do you actually mean $f \in D^n$ if $f^{(n)}(x)$ exists (but is not necessarily continuous) for every $x$?

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Are you sure that you don't want to say that $f \in D^k \iff f \in D^{k-1}$ and $f^{(k-1)} \in D^1$? I.e. you don't want to speak only of $f^{(k)}$, but also about $f^{(i)}$ with $0 \le i \le k-1$, don't you? I.e. $D^k$ means the functions of class $C^k$ - or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @AlexM. I'm fairly certain $f^{(k)}\implies f^{(i)},i<k$